# How to filter and count rows of a dataset which matches a measure output

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I have this dataset which is filtered by two slicers, practice name and project name. After that I have created two measures to obtain the latest release date and the version of the latest release name.

```
Last Release Date = 
    MAXX(
        ALLSELECTED(test_execution_summary), 
        test_execution_summary[Executed On]
    )

Last Release Name = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(test_cycle_details[Version]), 
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED(test_execution_summary), 
            test_execution_summary[Executed On]=[Last Release Date]
        )
    )
```

For my table in the report, which need to show the cycle details related to selected release version i am using the visual level filter below.

```
Is Latest Release Flag = 
    VAR LatestReleaseName = [Last Release Name]
 RETURN
    if (MAX(test_cycle_details[Version])=LatestReleaseName, 1, 0)
```

My table is like below.

[image]

Now I need to obtain the totals of each of those columns (test case count, bug count, reopen count) as separate cards. I tried by just adding the measures used for the columns into cards. But it just gives the totals related to the entire project. How can I apply the filtration of **Is Latest Release Flag** to these totals. I tried to create new measures to calculate total... but i can't figure out how to apply the measure in the filter condition. Tried below, but it is giving blank as output.

```
Total TestCase Count = 
        COUNTX(VALUES(test_execution_summary[Issue Key]), 
        IF(MAX(test_cycle_details[Version])=[Last Release Name], 1)
        )
```

Comment: Would you be open to adding a Calculated Column on `test_cycle_details` with a flag `Is Latest Release`?

Comment: My test_cycle_details table has the columns, CycleID, CycleName and Version. So when the dataset loads, it will add 1 against each matching row which belong to the latest release? Cz for each project there will be different versions. Or is this column going to be recalculated each time I select a project from my slicer?

Can't we do it via a measure?

Comment: Ah - wasn't aware that cycles can be across different projects. Will post an answer later on. Any possibility to share a link to a sample PBIX?

Comment: How about the schema of the model?

Answer (score 1):

This measure worked.

```
Total TestCase Count = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(test_execution_summary),
        FILTER(
            test_cycle_details, 
            test_cycle_details[Version] = [Last Release Name]
        )
    )
```